# Cassandra Document API support on Geospatial querying

Tags: solr, cassandra, geospatial, datastax, stargate

I'm trying to implement *geospatial* querying using stargate document API and I had no luck with that. I know *DataStax* is offering this feature with *solr_query* using *where* clause. But I want to implement using document API which is based on JSON. I just want to know does this supports this feature at all or not. If yes, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Stargate Document API exposes CRUD access to data stored in Cassandra db, I don't think it's possible to interact with "advanced workloads" components like DSE Search. Why not directly using the [Solr HTTP API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/usingSolrHttpApi.html) ?

Comment: @EricLavault I am already using document API for storing other information. Should I have to use the solr HTTP API in a separate database only for DSE Search and geospatial queries which is what you are saying?

Comment: I mean the document API provides only CRUD operations on the database, so you won't be able to make solr-like geospatial query using stargate (according to the documentation, I'm not faimilar with it though). But, since this database is indexed by DSE Search, you can directly use the Solr HTTP API to query the corresponding collection.